# OpenGL ES: using Tegra specific extensions (GL_EXT_texture_array)

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, tegra

I'm currently developing an OpenGL-ES application for Android using the NDK.
The application would greatly benefit from the following Open-GL extension:

GL_EXT_texture_array

(details here:  [GL_EXT_texture_arary](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/GL_EXT_texture_array.txt))
The extension is supported by my Tegra-3 device (Asus EeePad Transformer Prime Tf-201)

The issue I'm now facing is, that I have no clue how to make the extension available for my application as it is not included by the Open-GL ES API registry.
(see "Extension Specifications": http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/)
However I noticed an extension called "GL_NV_texture_array" which seems to be of the same use, but is not supported by my Tegra-3 device.

I'm aware of the possibility to include extensions using function pointers.
But I thought there might be a more comfortable way.
I have also found a header file (gl2ext_nv.h), which contains the necessary extension.
But when you search for it through google, the file is always part of particular projects, not something official.
I have also downloaded the Tegra Android Development Pack (2.0) in which neither this header file nor the desired extension is included.

Can anyone explain this to me, please?
How can I use Open-GL ES extension supported by my Tegra-3 device, 
which are seemingly not supported by any official Open-GL ES specific headers (in the NDK)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say that your Tegra 3 device supports `GL_EXT_texture_array` but *not* `GL_NV_texture_array`, I'm assuming that you determined that through a call to `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`.

`GL_NV_texture_array` is very similar to `GL_EXT_texture_array`, just limited to 2d texture arrays.  Not surprisingly, it uses many of the same constants as GL_EXT_texture_array, just with different names.

[GL_NV_texture_array](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/NV/NV_texture_array.txt):

```
TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_NV                             0x8C1A
TEXTURE_BINDING_2D_ARRAY_NV                     0x8C1D
MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS_NV                     0x88FF
FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_TEXTURE_LAYER_NV         0x8CD4
SAMPLER_2D_ARRAY_NV                             0x8DC1
```

[GL_EXT_texture_array](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_array.txt):

```
TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT                            0x8C1A
TEXTURE_BINDING_2D_ARRAY_EXT                    0x8C1D
MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS_EXT                    0x88FF
FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_TEXTURE_LAYER_EXT        0x8CD4
SAMPLER_2D_ARRAY_EXT                            0x8DC1
```

[This version of gl2ext_nv.h](https://bitbucket.org/evandromillian/ogre3d-for-marmalade/src/5ffc27af858d568b54cff272dd401e72748aceb7/RenderSystems/GLES2/include/EGL/gl2ext_nv.h) defines the constants for `GL_EXT_texture_array` but *not* for `GL_NV_texture_array`, so perhaps nVidia is using the the old name now.  If you can't find a more recent version of the header, just include this one.

To gain access to functions offered by GL extensions, use `eglGetProcAddress` to assign the function to a function pointer.

```
// The function pointer, declared in a header.
// You can put this in a class instance or at global scope.
// If the latter, declare it with "extern", and define the actual function
// pointer without "extern" in a single source file.
PFNGLFRAMEBUFFERTEXTURELAYEREXTPROC glFramebufferTextureLayerEXT;
```

In your function that checks for the presence of the GL_EXT_texture_array extension, if it's found, get the address of the function and store it in your function pointer.  With OpenGL-ES, that means asking EGL:

```
glFramebufferTextureEXT = (PFNGLFRAMEBUFFERTEXTURELAYEREXTPROC) eglGetProcAddress("glFramebufferTextureLayerEXT");
```

Now you can use the function just like it was part of regular OpenGL.

Comment: Alright! That really made things clearer to me.
It does not seem to be that hard as I expected it to be, but I didn't know how to do so.
I just defined the new constants in a header file and used the function pointer to access the function provided by GL_EXT_texture_array.
The code compiles and I can now try the stuff on the shader-side to see if everything works.
So, thank you for your kind explanation, that really helped me!
P.S.: yes, I determine the capabilities of the Tegra Chip by `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`